# How to return a NamedFile in a HttpResponse using Actix-web

Tags: rust, actix-web

I try to return a NamedFile in a HttpRespose
with this function

```
fn response(x: NamedFile)->HttpResponse{
        HttpResponse::Ok()
        .content_type(ContentType::html())
        .insert_header(("X-Hdr", "sample"))
        .body(x)
}
```

The function get called in my index file and returns the HttpRequest
is this even possible???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by introducing a new function that converts the content of the file into a single string

```
fn open(x: PathBuf) -> String{
    return fs::read_to_string(x)
        .expect("Something went wrong");
}
```

and used instead of NamedFile a String the function looks like this:

```
fn response(x: String, y:Response)->HttpResponse{

    match y{
        Response::OK => {
        HttpResponse::Ok()
        .content_type(ContentType::html())
        .insert_header(("X-Hdr", "sample"))
        .body(x)
        }
        Response::NOTOK => {
            HttpResponse::NotFound()
        .content_type(ContentType::html())
        .insert_header(("X-Hdr", "sample"))
        .body(x)
        }   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I was late to the party but I'll try my best to provide a good answer,

you can convert this

```
fn response(x: NamedFile)->HttpResponse{
    HttpResponse::Ok()
    .content_type(ContentType::html())
    .insert_header(("X-Hdr", "sample"))
    .body(x)
}
```

into this

```
#[post("/downloadfile")]
pub async fn download_file(req: HttpRequest, body: Json<CreateCommonBody>) -> impl Responder {
match NamedFile::open(&body.path) {
    Ok(fe) => NamedFile::into_response(fe, &req),
    Err(_) => HttpResponse::BadRequest().json("can't download file")
   }
}
```